# after android 13 in samsung one ui 5 update device's data/data not display in Android Studio Device File Explorer

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile, android-13, android-device-explorer

i update my **samsung** mobile to **one ui 5** **android 13** after that i can't access my mobile's **data/data** folder in Android Studio`
how to access now ?

[image]

Comment: If it's samsung please uninstall secure folder app
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74645969/8627144

Comment: no..not working i uninstall secure folder using adb but still same problame

Answer (score 1):

In Samsung because of **Secure folder** we can't access **data/data** folder in Android Studio, therefore follow the below steps to uninstall it :-[image]

After this you will be able to access it.

Comment: This does not work, it only removing the secure folder. Do you have any other idea?